# Web Audio API: How to unschedule pause without glitches?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm looking at the Web Audio API for my next project, and I'm confused by the lack of play/pause.

I need the following feature: user can click "pause", and the sound fades out in `N` seconds. After fadeout, the sound pauses. If "play" is clicked during the fadeout, the sound fades in back and never pauses.

The only solution I could find is the following, but I am not certain it prevents glitches. Are the steps after "click play" guaranteed to happen fast enough? Also, is there a simpler way?

With `source` currently playing, connected to a `gain` node and `ouput` node.

With `(t,o)` = (last time sound was started, offset then)
and `end` = 0

- On click pause,

  - `end := (o+N)%soundDuration`
  - schedule stop for `source` at time `currentTime+N`
  - set `gain` to fadeout
- On click play,

  - *if still fading out*: `(t,o) := (currentTime, o + (currentTime-t))`
  - *otherwise*: `(t,o) := (currentTime, end)`
  - start `source2` at offset `o`
  - connect `source2` to `gain` and `output`
  - set `gain` to fadein
  - disconnect `source` from its `gain` and `output`
  - `source := source2`

#### Edit

One way to avoid glitches while swapping nodes:

1. Don't disconnect `source` from its `gain` and `output` nodes.
2. Connect `source2` to the same 2 nodes.
3. Schedule `source` to stop in 1ms and `source2` to start in 1ms at offset `(o + (currentTime - t) + 1ms)`.
4. If necessary for GC purposes, schedule disconnect of `source` at a later time.

Comment: I don't clearly understand why you do disconnect the nodes ? also, you may be interested in [exponentialRampToValueAtTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/exponentialRampToValueAtTime) and [linearRampToValueAtTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/linearRampToValueAtTime)

Comment: It may not be necessary! I don't know much about the API for now, so maybe `stop()` is enough to have `source` be GC'ed later. The functions you mentioned would be used on some `parameter` node connected to the `gain` node, but I don't think it is related to my problem.